# Defining User defined Guid

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I want to define User Define Guid in C#. I want to insert this in my Guid object:

> dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.

When I do this:

```
Guid user = "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
```

I get the err: System cannot convert from String to System.Guid. What should I do here?

Comment: Just curious as to WHY you would want this.  Given the laziness of users, there's a high probability that users will just enter in all one character like you've shown and then there will be duplicates - by definition NOT a "globally unique" id.

Comment: I am doing some unit testing. Thats why...and one of my functions need Guid as a param.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable.  Thanks for satisfying my curiosity!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
Guid user = Guid.Parse("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
```

Note that when you print the guid out again, it will be formatted differently:

```
// Prints dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd
Console.WriteLine(user);
```

You could call the `Guid(string)` constructor instead, but personally I prefer calling the `Parse` method - it's more descriptive of what's going on, and it follows the same convention as `int.Parse` etc. On the other hand, `Guid.Parse` was only introduced in .NET 4 - if you're on an older version of .NET, you'll need to use the constructor. I believe there are some differences in terms of which values will be accepted by the different calls, but I don't know the details.

Comment: To get the same string in the output, use [`user.ToString("N")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) must be 32 characters formated properly and it would also be called like this

```
Guid user = new Guid("aa4e075f-3504-4aab-9b06-9a4104a91cf0");
```

you could also have one generated

```
Guid user = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Guid.Parse handles the given input without any problem, as does the Guid constructor.

Comment: LOL! Where you got this Guid from?

Comment: That's what they typically resemble klm :)

Comment: @kim9971 most guids will look similar to this, they are generated to be unique. Try Guid.newGuid() or even http://newguid.com/

Comment: Just another fact - you can also generate a GUID in Visual Studio under  Tools > Create GUID. :)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [Guid.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx) for this:

```
Guid user = Guid.Parse("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Guid user = new Guid("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
```

Hope this helps!
N.S.